# Xcode build fails if I add a label to storyboard

Tags: xcode, storyboard

My xcode 4.5 project seems to have gone haywire.  I'm getting the following error:

The document "MainStoryboard_iPad.storyboard" could not be opened. The operation could not be completed. (com.apple.InterfaceBuilder error -1.)

I've spent hours restoring from git and rebuilding screens to make things work again. But now I'm getting the error when a add a simple label to an empty ViewController with no segues. Any ideas? Is there some way to check for corruption in various project files? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the build settings to check if the porject is building for Ipad, Iphone or both

Answer (score 0):

This may also occur when an object in the storyboard is linked to an IBOutlet which does not exist anymore.